# Android Emulator so slow

Tags: android, android-emulator, performance

I know there has been quite a few posts on this but all the solutions given in these posts have not worked.

I made a Android 3.2 emulator and am trying to run a hello world application. I set the device ram size to 1024(any bigger and the emulator will crash and give this error)

```
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I am on windows 7 64bit edition. As I said I am trying to run a hello world application that. I tried to use the snapshot feature to make it load faster but the emulator sits on the "android" logo page for like 5 minutes.

Even once the emulator loads up and I try to click around on backbuttons and other default applications on the emulator it is like a slideshow.

Comment: The solution is to plug in an actual Android 3.2 device. Sucks, I know.

Comment: I would invite people to try this option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17394245/1204249

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unless you really need some of the new functionalities of 3.2 I would recommend you develop on an earlier sdk... I personally use 1.6 and 2.1 for most of my apps and the difference in load time and general emulator speed is enormous.

EDIT:
*especially considering you are only writing helloWorld at this present*

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. I thought it was my hardware but I got the latest emulator and it still sometimes crashes but by taking a snapshot I've got my loading times down from 10 minutes to 1 minute.

I'd verify those times, and give you my version numbers but I run it off of external storage and it seems I've since uninstalled Java :(

It was working with the last release about 6 months ago. The rush to update Android SDK stopped about that time too, as I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Please try 896 instead of 1024. It seems like a bug with 1024 value.

Comment: no it's not a bug with 1024 value, I've tried 512 and 896 and it's still taking ages to load

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ADT Bundle for development, then go to AVD Manager and select Device definitions tab on the top.

Then click new device button and create a new device with minimum resources. And create a new virtual device with the newly created device.

It will work like a charm. I dont know the exact reason why. but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try Android x86. It's much faster than the Google Android emulator. Follow these steps:

1. Install VirtualBox.
2. Download the ISO file that you need.
3. Create a virtual machine as Linux 2.6/Other Linux, 512 Mb RAM, HD 2 GB. Network: PCnet-Fast III, attached to NAT. You can also use a bridged adapter, but you need a DHCP server in your environment.
4. Install Android x86 on the emulator, run it.
5. Press Alt+F1, type netcfg, remember the IP address, press Alt+F7.
6. Run cmd on your Windows XP system, change the directory to your Android tools directory, type adb connect .
7. Start Eclipse, open the ADT plugin, find the device, and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too, but using the android emulator is very low, another option is to emulate a device using a Virtual Machine.

In this case, you have to install Virtual Box, then download an ISO file (android 4.4 RC2) and the proceed to install and configure. In my opinion it is a better way to test your app.

http://edwindh.blogspot.com/2014/07/emular-uma-tablet-ou-smartphone-com.html